# Google BigQuery SQL: Parse multi level JSON (list +json+list+json) to Columns

Tags: sql, json, google-bigquery

I have Json string with two levels: list[json{list[json]}]:

```
UserID               Json_List
100     [{"application_charge":{"id":13409353813,"name":"Starter","api_client_id":2485321},"usage_charges":[{"id":48216805,"description":"Extras","price":"60.70"}]}]
200     [{"application_charge":{"id":13409353814,"name":"Starter","api_client_id":2485322},"usage_charges":[{"id":48216890,"description":"Extras","price":"80.79"}]}]
```

Need Output like table :

```
UserID  application_charge.id   name    api_client_id   usage_charges.id    description   price
100      13409353813          Starter    2485321        48216805           Extras         60.7
200      13409353814          Starter    2485322        48216890           Extras         80.79
```

I manage to pull out the first step "application_charge" but do not understand how to get to the next step "usage_charges"

```
select  
  UserID,
  json_extract_scalar(json, '$.application_charge.id')  as id,
  json_extract_scalar(json, '$.application_charge.name')  as name,
  json_extract_scalar(json, '$.application_charge.api_client_id')  as api_client_id
from `be-prod-data.retailers_billing_data_production.shopify_application_charges`,
unnest(json_extract_array( json_list, '$')) json
```

How can I extract data from the second stage ??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just one more `unnest(json_extract_array(...`

```
with mytable as (
  select 100 as userid, '[{"application_charge":{"id":13409353813,"name":"Starter","api_client_id":2485321},"usage_charges":[{"id":48216805,"description":"Extras","price":"60.70"}]}]' as json_list union all
  select 200, '[{"application_charge":{"id":13409353814,"name":"Starter","api_client_id":2485322},"usage_charges":[{"id":48216890,"description":"Extras","price":"80.79"}]}]'
)
select  
  UserID,
  json_extract_scalar(json, '$.application_charge.id')  as id,
  json_extract_scalar(json, '$.application_charge.name')  as name,
  json_extract_scalar(json, '$.application_charge.api_client_id')  as api_client_id,
  json_extract_scalar(nested, '$.id')  as usage_charges_id,
from mytable,
unnest(json_extract_array( json_list, '$')) json, unnest(json_extract_array(json, '$.usage_charges')) as nested
```

[image]